# Spring JPA projection problem with subquery

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, subquery, projection

I'm using JPA projections but it fails when my query contains subquery.
For exemple :

```
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "student_id")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

}
```

Here is the interface for projection :

```
public interface StudentProjection {
    Integer getId();
}
```

And repository :

```
@Query("select s from Student s where s.id = 88831")
List<StudentProjection> findProjections();
```

With this code everything works fine, and repo returns a list of EleveProjection.

But if I change query to this (i.e. fetching id by subselect - just for example):

```
@Query("select s from Student s where s.id = (select max(88831) from Student)")
List<StudentProjection> findProjections();
```

... method *findProjections()* returns a list of ***org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap***

And obviously it's not possible to execute getId() on this object (exception thrown).

It looks like a bug in Spring data JPA.
I'm currently using version 2.2.4.RELEASE.

Any idea on how to use subqueries with JPA projections ?

Thank you

Comment: I've submitted the test case on Spring Jira.
I'ts a bug, I'll test the workaround given in ticket comments.

Answer (score 0):

The content of `@Query` respect Jpql spec so it is not about spring data.

Try this 
`@Query("select s from Student s where s.id in (select max(88831) from Student)")
List<StudentProjection> findProjections();`

AFAIK you can use clauses `exists` and `in` with subqueries in jpql...

Comment: why not just `select s.id from Student s where s.id....` ? What your projection needs is the id ...

Comment: I've simplified for the example. In real life, Student projection have 10 - 12 fields.

Comment: did you try with a native one ? -> `@Query("select id from Student where id in (select max(88831) from Student), nativeQuery=true)`

Comment: With a native query retrieving only id, JPA will return the whole object Student ?

Comment: Nope only what you need...so here for your example the `id`